# C++: Adding node to doubly linked list in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to add nodes to a doubly linked list in alphabetical order with respect to the title element of the node. So far, I've tried iterating through the list and checking for the case `(strcmp(title, currTitle) > 0)`. However, iteration does not work (for reasons I'm not certain of), as the attempt listed below does not add any items to the linked list.

The set of four conditions for the if - else block successfully adds items to the list when not implemented with the attempt at sorting.

```
void SongList::addSongSorted(const Song &aSong)
{
    //sort inputs to the list by alphabetical order of the entire title
    char title[MAX_CHAR];
    char currTitle[MAX_CHAR];
    aSong.getTitle(title);

    Node * newNode = new Node(aSong);

    Node * curr = head;
    //Increment through list as added...this does not work
    for(curr = head; curr; curr = curr->next)
    {

        if(strcmp(title, currTitle) > 0)
        {

            if(!head)
            {
                head = newNode;
                tail = newNode;
                head->next = NULL;
                head->prev = NULL;
            }
            else if(head->prev == NULL)
            {
                newNode->next = head;
                head = newNode;
                newNode->prev = NULL;
            }

            else if(head->next == NULL)
            {
                curr->next = newNode;
                newNode->prev = curr;
                newNode->next = NULL;
                tail = newNode;
            }

            else
            {
                newNode->next = curr->next;
                newNode->prev = curr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How is it that incrementing through the list and adding at a node based on comparison of elements does not work? What is a solution?

Comment: Why you use array of chars ? Use `std::string`

Comment: @Inline This is for a homework assignment

Comment: You do not handle `strcmp(title, currTitle) <= 0`

Comment: @GMichael The idea was to check all elements of the list, and initiate insertion upon reaching that condition.

Comment: @0x1000001 What will happen if first insertions fall in the missing case?

Comment: Are you meaning to add in your second item as `head`'s previous element? Because `head->prev` should always be `NULL`, as `head` should be the first item.

Comment: @GMichael Nothing should happen. The only time insertion should occur is when `strcmp(title, currTitle) > 0`.

Comment: @naffarn Perhaps I should replace `head->prev` with `curr->prev`?

Comment: I've answered below. Your assumption that insertion only happens if `strcmp(title, currTitle) > 0` is incorrect - if `title` is alphabetically before `currTitle`, `strcmp` returns `-1`, and it returns '0' if they are equal. You must cater to all these cases, and they won't be inserted as your code is now.

Comment: Oh,  sorry,  yea.  Just add `curr = curr->next` when you don't insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @verbose says, you never really assign a value to `currTitle`, try using `curr.getTitle(currTitle)` at the start of the loop, or using `curr->title` in its place.

With regards to inserting in order, you needn't worry about `head`'s previous value, only if the head itself is null, or the title comes before the head. You should iterate through the list, if the title comes after the current node, and the next node is null, you set curr to the next element (done in the for loop) and check again. If The next element is NULL, and the title comes after the current one, you have reached the end of the list, may insert the song, and break. 
If the song title comes before the current one, or is equal, you insert the new song before the current one and return. Example code below:

```
if(!head)
{
    // set head to currnode, as you have
    head = newNode;
    tail = head;
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
    return; // no need to iterate through the list
}
bool inserted = false;
while (!inserted) 
{
    curr->song.getTitle(currTitle);
    if(strcmp(title, currTitle) > 0)
    {
        // If the title goes after the current title 
        if(curr->next == NULL)
        {
            // End of the list, insert after this node
            curr->next = newNode;
            newNode->prev = curr;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            tail = newNode;
            inserted = true;
        }
        // If we don't insert here, we iterate again
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    else 
    {
        // If the title is the same, or comes before the current title, insert before curr
        newNode->prev = curr->prev;
        newNode->next = curr;
        curr->prev = newNode;
        if (curr == head)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        inserted = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I've altered my code with and according to your recommendations. However, it is not allowing the entire list to be input to the list, and only sorts some of the entries. Input and output in a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/T3uM06kz

Comment: Are the strings printed there the song titles?

Comment: Yes, Song # is the song title that is being compared

Comment: Hi,  from what I can make of your output,  you still only add if `strcmp > 0` which is incorrect. Did you add the else statement? When you get to song 2, it should be inserted between 1 and 7, but this won't happen unless you account for `strcmp <= 0`,  which is what my else statement is for.

Comment: I've added the else statement - the I/O in the pastebin is from a test of your code.

Comment: My code didn't have `curr.getTitle(currTitle)` in the for loop,  just added it, that'd be the problem if you just copy/pasted

Comment: Yes, that was there, just inside the for loop: `curr->song.getTitle(currTitle);`

Comment: Ah, the problem is that I'm only iterating once. However, switching to `while(curr)` is causing a runtime error.

Comment: Using while(pointer) is a bad idea. Use `bool inserted = false;` just before the while loop. Do `while (!inserted) ` and set `inserted = true` when you insert the song. Break statements can be removed.

Comment: Ok, but I just realized that the `while` loop will not repeat over the list multiple times, which is required with the current logic. Any ideas on how to loop over it multiple times?

Comment: There is no change with the updates applied. No more than 4 nodes will be added to the list via the sorting method.

Comment: Have you tried adding print statements to see what it's doing?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the two strings but the second doesn't appear to ever be initialized. Presumably `aSong.getTitle(title)` copies the title of the current song to the `title[]` array. But when is anything ever copied to `currTitle[]`?

So the elements of `currTitle[]` are garbage, and the comparison won't work. To fix this, compare the title of the song you want to insert to the titles of the songs already in the list. You probably want something like `strcmp(title, curr->title)`.

Of course you first need to check that a song actually exists before doing the comparison. Start by checking whether a song exists at `head`, and if not, insert the song as the head song. If there is already a song at the head, compare the two titles and determine whether the new song should be the new head, or whether it should go somewhere after the head. The rest of the logic should be straightforward.